# act on the selected item in ListView

Tags: java, android, android-studio

im have a layout named type_of_dairy with below code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:layoutDirection="rtl"

    android:weightSum="1">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="Type"
        android:id="@+id/iceCreamType"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_weight="0.05"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"/>

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        android:id="@+id/listView"
        android:layout_weight="0.26"
        android:background="#999900"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="Flavour"
        android:id="@+id/iceCreamFlavor"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_weight="0.05"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"/>

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="58dp"
        android:id="@+id/listView2"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:background="#999900"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="89dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Apply"
        android:id="@+id/countOficeCream"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.05" />
    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Cancel"
        android:id="@+id/iceCreamReject"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.05" />

</LinearLayout>
```

as you see i have two `ListView`, i have filled out the first `ListView` from my DB, a field of a table of my DB has selected to fill in this `ListView(@+id/listView)` and there are two buttons,i want that as i selected an item from the first `ListView(@+id/listView)` , the second `ListView (@+id/listView2)` fill out with another field of my DB,

```
public class Dairy extends Activity {
    Button returnBack;
    Statement statement;
    Statement statement2;
    ListView dairyType;
    ListView dairyFlavour;
    ArrayList<String> typeArray;
    ArrayList<String> dairyArray;
    ArrayAdapter<String> typeAdapter;
    ArrayAdapter<String> flavorAapter;
    String typeString, flavourString;
    private Object view;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.type_of_dairy);



        dairyType = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
        dairyFlavour = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView2);
        typeArray = new ArrayList<String>();
        typeAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(),
        android.R.layout.simple_list_item_single_choice, typeArray);

        flavorAapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(),
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_single_choice, dairyArray);

        try
        {
            ConnectionHelper connectionHelper = new ConnectionHelper();
            statement = connectionHelper.getConnection().createStatement();
            ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery("select Name from tblProductCategory where TypeId=1");

            if(resultSet.next()) {
                do {
                    typeString=resultSet.getString(resultSet.findColumn("Name"));
                    typeArray.add(typeString);
                    dairyType.setAdapter(typeAdapter);
                }while(resultSet.next());
            }
        }
        catch (SQLException e)
        {

        }

        dairyType.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                try{
                    ConnectionHelper connectionHelper = new ConnectionHelper();
                    statement2 = connectionHelper.getConnection().createStatement();
                    ResultSet resultSet = statement2.executeQuery("select username from tblUser");
                    if(resultSet.next())

                    {
                        do {
                            flavourString = resultSet.getString(resultSet.findColumn("UserName"));
                            dairyArray.add(flavourString);
                            dairyFlavour.setAdapter(flavorAapter);
                        } while (resultSet.next());
                    }
                }catch (SQLException e)
                {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Problem detected", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        });
```

i want that as i select an item from first `ListView(dairyType)`, some data from another table of my DB be selected and shown in second `ListView(dairyFlavour)`, and this part i said this :

```
    dairyType.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            try{
                ConnectionHelper connectionHelper = new ConnectionHelper();
                statement2 = connectionHelper.getConnection().createStatement();
                ResultSet resultSet = statement2.executeQuery("select username from tblUser");
                if(resultSet.next())

                {
                    do {
                        flavourString = resultSet.getString(resultSet.findColumn("UserName"));
                        dairyArray.add(flavourString);
                        dairyFlavour.setAdapter(flavorAapter);
                    } while (resultSet.next());
                }
            }catch (SQLException e)
            {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Problem detected", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    });
```

but i get myAppclication stopped in my android device and `javaNullPointExecption` in android studio,
However by this connection to DB i have shown the first`ListView`and Loged into the App.

Comment: provide crash log plz.

Comment: @HarishVats here is the Exeption 10-04 12:19:15.998  16967-16967/com.theonlyone.behtakapp E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.theonlyone.behtakapp, PID: 16967
java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.theonlyone.behtakapp.Dairy$1.onItemClick(Dairy.java:117)
at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:299)
at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1158)

Comment: and continue with this :
at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:3020)
at android.widget.AbsListView$3.run(AbsListView.java:3884)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:808)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:103)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5299)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)at

Comment: see my answer. and if It helps. upvote it. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your given code, It seems you forgot to initialise the "dairyArray".
Initialise it first , then add Strings to it.

You might be getting error on "dairyArray.add(flavourString);" , as dairyArray is not initialised.
I hope it will work.

Comment: What a stupid mistake, Thx alot @Harish , and i would like to answer this question too.
as i select first ListView for the first time and the second ListView is shown, its good, but for second time i select  another item from first ListView, the previous content of second Listview still there, 
how can i remove the previous action contents?

Comment: use secondAdapterName.notifyDataSetChanged(); 
It will reflect the changes in listview.

Comment: I added this method here, but doesnt work

    flavourString = resultSet.getString(resultSet.findColumn("UserName"));
                            dairyArray.add(flavourString);
                            dairyFlavour.setAdapter(flavorAapter);
                            flavorAapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
:-(

Comment: ohh I understood your prblm.. before adding values to that array, do clear it every time. :)

Comment: Yes, it is.
 Maybe I will disturb you later.
 LOL

Thx alot Harish 
:-)

Comment: I have another Problem, can i ask here or post a question?

Comment: another question, if it not related to listview.

Comment: I will, for sure. for now it says : 
you dont have earned a total of 15 reputatoin.

Comment: oh.. okay okay... no prob. :)

Comment: Now i want to add the number of second ListView Item that user entered in EditText via iceCreameRegistration.
I Used the first ListView to filter and reach the second ListView and now want to add the number of second ListView(that end user entered in my EditText) and enter it in my DB via iceCreameRegistration.
How can i do? in button cliclListener? so have can i get index of second ListView, can you give a sample?
I really appreciate it.

Comment: Icecream registration? I dnt have any knwldg regarding this.

Comment: iceCreamRegistration is my button name as you know, the better name is countOfIceCream. Anyways, i want that end user select first ListView and then second ListView be generated, and then insert a number in EditText and click on that button(iceCreamRegistration), so the count will be inserted into my DB.

Comment: Its a simple logic.. u have to think it and write it. Stack ovrflow is for helping solve major issue and problems. but nor for giving logics.

Comment: Thx alot again, im brand new to android programming and i really dont like ask questions and always wanted to solve my problems by myself and give solutions to others, i just know a few basic concepts of android, and just know OOP, and a liitle experience of java programming, and today was last day to do this project and i didnt ask any questions and i have done this by googling till now, And as you saw i in my post, the question i asked was stupid cause i forgot to assign the dairyArray, i had one week to do this project, for sure you can do this in one or two days,anyways,again Thx.

Comment: and i deleted that question in stackexchange.
Thx again.

Comment: Last year at this time I was also in the same position.. :) All the best. keep learning. :D

Answer (score 0):

As my Friend @harish said i didnt assign dairyArray in my code, so that related adapter returns nothing,
But i act on the selected item via this code :

```
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String str;
        str=flavorAapter.getItem(dairyFlavour.getCheckedItemPosition()).toString();
```

And then return the str.